# Dúvida em diagrama de classe

Tags: classes, modelagem, uml

Boa tarde.

Segue a questão sobre diagrama de classe com o diagrama que consegui fazer.

Descrever o diagrama de classes para um sistema simples de reserva e ocupação de quartos
para um hotel. O sistema deve armazenar reservas feitas por um funcionário de um ou mais
quartos para um determinado cliente. O funcionário deve ser capaz de verificar se um quarto
está ocupado ou não, inserir ou alterar os dados de um cliente, realizar a reserva de um quarto
para um cliente. Considere os atributos de todas as classes como privados. Cada cliente e
funcionário deve possuir: nome, rg, endereço, telefone. O cliente ainda deve possuir um campo
que armazene a quantidade de ocupações já realizadas por ele. Um quarto pode ser simples ou
luxo e deve indicar o número de camas e o tipo de cada uma delas (solteiro ou casal).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A representação está correta? Tive grande dificuldade em adicionar os métodos, os que adicionei na classe Cliente e Quarto estão corretos? Há outros à adicionar?

Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Eu adicionaria o método "reservar" em "Quarto" levando em consideração "reservas feitas por um funcionário" e "realizar a reserva de um quarto para um cliente".

Answer (score 0):

Eu adicionaria os seguintes métodos:

- na classe Cliente: inserirCliente(), alterarCliente();
- na classe Quarto: reservar();
- na classe Funcionário: inserirFuncionario(), cadastrarFuncionario(); (apesar de não estar escrito, você vai precisar cadastrar o funcionário também.

Quanto aos atributos, quando você indica que uma classe está relacionada a outra significa que algum campo entre as classes está relacionado. Então, por exemplo, na classe Quarto você não indica que ela terá informações sobre a cama, apenas que a classe cama tem uma relação de um para muitos com ela. Usando este exemplo, eu adicionaria os seguintes atributos:

Classe cama:
idCama: int;

Classe quarto:
idCamas: int;
quantCamas: int;

---

Pessoa:
idPessoa: int;

Cliente:
idPessoa: int

Funcionário:
idPessoa: int;

E assim por diante.